# Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, spring.net

Below details of the error, if someone can help me I am grateful.

```
Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia.Implementacoes.GenericDAO' from assembly 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.



Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Could not load type 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia.Implementacoes.GenericDAO' from assembly 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia.Implementacoes.GenericDAO' from assembly 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia.Implementacoes.GenericDAO' from assembly 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +67
   Spring.Core.TypeResolution.TypeResolver.LoadTypeDirectlyFromAssembly(TypeAssemblyHolder typeInfo) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeResolution\TypeResolver.cs:123
   Spring.Core.TypeResolution.TypeResolver.Resolve(String typeName) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeResolution\TypeResolver.cs:75
   Spring.Core.TypeResolution.GenericTypeResolver.Resolve(String typeName) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeResolution\GenericTypeResolver.cs:97
   Spring.Core.TypeResolution.CachedTypeResolver.Resolve(String typeName) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeResolution\CachedTypeResolver.cs:107
   Spring.Core.TypeResolution.TypeResolutionUtils.ResolveType(String typeName) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeResolution\TypeResolutionUtils.cs:106
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectDefinition.ResolveObjectType() in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectDefinition.cs:640
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.ResolveObjectType(RootObjectDefinition rod, String objectName) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectFactory.cs:1096

[CannotLoadObjectTypeException: Cannot resolve type [SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia.Implementacoes.GenericDAO, SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia] for object with name 'GenericDAO' defined in config [C:\Users\eggtech024\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent\SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Web\web.config#spring/objects] line 1]
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.ResolveObjectType(RootObjectDefinition rod, String objectName) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectFactory.cs:1100
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.PreInstantiateSingletons() in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\DefaultListableObjectFactory.cs:472
   Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.Refresh() in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\AbstractApplicationContext.cs:1017
   Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext..ctor(WebApplicationContextArgs args) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebApplicationContext.cs:125
   Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext..ctor(String name, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] configurationLocations) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebApplicationContext.cs:82
   _dynamic_Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext..ctor(Object[] ) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Caching\AspNetCache.cs:126
   Spring.Reflection.Dynamic.SafeConstructor.Invoke(Object[] arguments) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Reflection\Dynamic\DynamicConstructor.cs:116
   Spring.Context.Support.RootContextInstantiator.InvokeContextConstructor(ConstructorInfo ctor) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:563
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextInstantiator.InstantiateContext() in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:508
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.InstantiateContext(IApplicationContext parentContext, Object configContext, String contextName, Type contextType, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] resources) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:351
   Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler.InstantiateContext(IApplicationContext parent, Object configContext, String contextName, Type contextType, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] resources) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebContextHandler.cs:129
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.Create(Object parent, Object configContext, XmlNode section) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:289

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia.Implementacoes.GenericDAO' from assembly 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult) +199
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) +1153
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) +1468
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey) +41
   System.Web.HttpContext.GetSection(String sectionName) +52
   System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetSection(String sectionName) +57
   System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String configKey) +6
   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName) +78
   Spring.Util.ConfigurationUtils.GetSection(String sectionName) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Util\ConfigurationUtils.cs:71
   Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext.GetContextInternal(String virtualPath) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebApplicationContext.cs:335
   Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext.GetRootContext() in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebApplicationContext.cs:223
   Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule.Init(HttpApplication app) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebSupportModule.cs:175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +43
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +828
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +327
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902631/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-spring-core)? This one looks pretty similar to me.

Answer (score 1):

is the type `SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia.Implementacoes.GenericDAO` in an assembly named `SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia` ? usually the assembly name is something like `SpringNet` and you can check that from the project properties

Comment: Good morning, then some examples that were caught in the net with this structure, but did what you recommended to remove the doubt and the following error occurs:

Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type from string value 'SpringNet.NHibernate.Fluent.Persistencia.Implementacoes.GenericDAO, SpringNet'.

If I remember the design or assembly is the namespace that the file is located, but I appreciate the help.